# Image failed to align vertically inside td

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, vertical-alignment

Please run the very simple snippet below.
You can see that spaces on top doesn't equal to spaces on bottom.
How to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 20px; border: 1px solid black">
        <img style="height:10px; width:10px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red;"></image>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT: @James provided a solution that change TD display to flex. Beside this, anyone knows why 'vertical-align' doesn't work in this simple case?**

Answer (score 1):

Try assign it to its parent element will work.

A little off-topic suggestion, maybe not use too many inline style, they are too messy.

```css
td{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;border: 1px solid black">
        <img style="height:10px; width:10px;  border: 1px solid red;"></image>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the flex solution!
And I use inline style just for simplicity. 
Btw, do you know why the simple "vertical-align" doesn't work? is that a browser bug? I tested on both firefox and Chrome and get the same result.

Comment: @timepp, there is nothing wrong with the broswer. It is because the vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element. It decides how the element deal with its child element. You have to apply it to the parent element. So in your code, you have to apply `vertical-align` to its parent element which is `td`

Comment: adding `vertical-align` to `td` doesn't help

Comment: @timepp, wonder how doesn't it work or help?

Comment: sorry for the late response, but what I mean is that without "setting td display to flex", only setting "vertial-align" doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @timepp, because the vertical align doesn't work for block level element (the common  block html element is <div><h1>, according to mdn: `you can't use it to vertically align block-level elements.` You have to change how the element display (not display:block)

Comment: exactly! You helped me to recall what I just learned recently that element display style can changes something that's easy to make mistake. It's required to learn MDN carefully before I can fine-tune complicated layout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> @James provided a solution that change TD display to flex. Beside this, anyone knows why 'vertical-align' doesn't work in this simple case?

This appears to be associated with an img element being a replaced element.

If we make that element a div instead then it aligns in the vertical direction centrally:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 20px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="height:10px; width:10px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

If we give the img display: block it also aligns vertically in the middle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 20px; border: 1px solid black">
        <img style="display: block; height:10px; width:10px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Hmm, a workaround but not a complete explanation as I confess to not understanding non block elements fully.